# Taking for loop results to a dataframe

Tags: r

Im running this code:

```
#Importar los datos
boyanza <- read_excel("Desktop/Tesina - Boyanza del ITBIS/Data/Data ITBIS:PIB Trimestral.xlsx")
boyanza <- boyanza%>%select(Sector,Fecha,lpib,lrecaudacion)

#Obtener los nombres de los sectores para separarlos al momento de estimar
serie_unica <- unique(boyanza$Sector)

#Estimacion por cada sector
Modelo_MCO <- function(i) {

Sector_elegido <- boyanza %>% 
    filter(Sector == serie_unica[i]) #Estimar cada serie por separado

  MCO <- lm(Sector_elegido$lrecaudacion ~ Sector_elegido$lpib) #Ejecutar el modelo MCO

  #Probar raiz unitaria / cointegracion

}

lapply(1:length(serie_unica), Modelo_MCO)
```

My problem is that the results appear in an undesirable way. I want to get each result in a dataframe with their `Sector` name (i dont even know which result belongs to who when i perform the for loop) and coefficients. Also, I plan to keep adding things to the for loop as unit root test and other things which should also appear in the desired dataframe.

My desired output would be a dataframe with 6 variables: `Sector`,`Intercept`,`Coefficient`,`Intercept p-value`,`Coefficient p-value` and `Unit root test` for each variable in the for loop.

This is a subset of my data:

```
structure(list(Sector = c("Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura"
), Fecha = c("2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2008 Q1", 
"2008 Q2", "2008 Q3", "2008 Q4", "2009 Q1", "2009 Q2", "2009 Q3", 
"2009 Q4", "2010 Q1", "2010 Q2", "2010 Q3", "2010 Q4", "2011 Q1", 
"2011 Q2", "2011 Q3", "2011 Q4", "2012 Q1", "2012 Q2", "2012 Q3", 
"2012 Q4", "2013 Q1", "2013 Q2", "2013 Q3", "2013 Q4", "2014 Q1", 
"2014 Q2", "2014 Q3", "2014 Q4", "2015 Q1", "2015 Q2", "2015 Q3", 
"2015 Q4", "2016 Q1", "2016 Q2", "2016 Q3", "2016 Q4", "2017 Q1", 
"2017 Q2", "2017 Q3", "2017 Q4", "2018 Q1", "2018 Q2", "2018 Q3", 
"2018 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2008 Q1", 
"2008 Q2", "2008 Q3", "2008 Q4", "2009 Q1", "2009 Q2", "2009 Q3", 
"2009 Q4", "2010 Q1", "2010 Q2", "2010 Q3", "2010 Q4", "2011 Q1", 
"2011 Q2", "2011 Q3", "2011 Q4", "2012 Q1", "2012 Q2", "2012 Q3", 
"2012 Q4", "2013 Q1", "2013 Q2", "2013 Q3", "2013 Q4", "2014 Q1", 
"2014 Q2", "2014 Q3", "2014 Q4", "2015 Q1", "2015 Q2", "2015 Q3", 
"2015 Q4", "2016 Q1", "2016 Q2", "2016 Q3", "2016 Q4", "2017 Q1", 
"2017 Q2", "2017 Q3", "2017 Q4", "2018 Q1", "2018 Q2", "2018 Q3", 
"2018 Q4"), lpib = c(23.9208192513736, 23.9547793577876, 23.7113615363005, 
23.9551561816675, 23.9791871131267, 24.0609327260839, 23.8522054499151, 
24.0672619240971, 24.0439628065799, 24.08862751044, 23.8191462398426, 
24.0489012378328, 24.1342125700793, 24.2363749536441, 23.9301951603667, 
24.1758581146702, 24.1553163277134, 24.269228441101, 24.0423988905311, 
24.1680724981159, 24.2146417516396, 24.3370349486954, 23.9721365153744, 
24.2250024811208, 24.2581482159441, 24.4043429274765, 24.0991585782936, 
24.299670204971, 24.3285037210178, 24.4382015210812, 24.1932843840038, 
24.4599687669099, 24.4790995700253, 24.5509178674757, 24.338977945028, 
24.6336525132489, 24.5911964739263, 24.695033731291, 24.4769376944737, 
24.6039150575164, 24.5981318722398, 24.755039330747, 24.5199473144748, 
24.7136028738888, 24.6989671055154, 24.831274745995, 24.6085743595799, 
24.7352657879472, 24.7319647582932, 24.7798391526453, 24.8149774885031, 
24.8821010050744, 24.8558392232244, 24.9701910228009, 24.9503173375001, 
24.9501614508357, 24.8522534989671, 24.9379219931171, 24.9201527857609, 
24.9805072834487, 24.9724691695314, 25.0618973035633, 25.0438813138428, 
25.116853540493, 25.0816465995181, 25.1474051066843, 25.1485676841393, 
25.2008558670854, 25.1590422450739, 25.2244062436121, 25.2046104101159, 
25.2755162410203, 25.1888680726842, 25.2901601006579, 25.2897662868454, 
25.3564698732644, 25.2862362685789, 25.38353198895, 25.400731741936, 
25.4816147161362, 25.4105749125337, 25.4835592423713, 25.5034625326161, 
25.5662013831766, 25.4657880856982, 25.5766373773005, 25.5478739074007, 
25.6314476014617, 25.5560004217414, 25.6215416376154, 25.6054785357995, 
25.6964258190478, 25.6534089669307, 25.756389929803, 25.7214097882784, 
25.7909791673757), lrecaudacion = c(17.3165532745961, 17.5254173792703, 
17.7467477823162, 17.5808879830509, 17.6415398502254, 17.6764507731631, 
17.6380463968909, 17.4512529136651, 17.406225763291, 17.6530255112174, 
17.6553928856147, 17.448877302148, 17.5206625731235, 17.6725343233053, 
17.766425875705, 18.1696094586812, 17.777201932113, 17.5443784626572, 
17.5096720403233, 17.6231117987477, 17.5944826852452, 17.8676508866123, 
17.7121597816971, 17.6023653836924, 17.5991975078308, 17.694213627511, 
17.8822726638377, 17.9555449536108, 17.8783488578582, 18.2514969193021, 
18.2820155091685, 18.5125024965362, 18.2700852192986, 18.1048409050765, 
18.1106238822944, 18.1115957383498, 18.1996426513536, 18.1442227936413, 
18.1443607802437, 18.3144370714263, 18.2171204831367, 18.2790874105239, 
18.1391719826773, 18.1861918357785, 18.6487752293812, 18.7988843607231, 
18.672835240355, 18.938792447297, 21.5540727517896, 21.670861418649, 
21.6841512776958, 21.7581534954001, 21.7331525529579, 21.9123919728989, 
21.9097913180685, 21.8399537723418, 21.9227967908448, 21.9822891684126, 
22.0428459784791, 22.060711282171, 22.0879051223452, 22.1220660921817, 
22.0833817549598, 21.9323510784567, 21.8631500561848, 21.8018369475668, 
21.7593763504405, 21.8867036097524, 22.014404323807, 22.0265238580423, 
22.1921771821384, 22.2188301834985, 22.3233094942489, 22.3608952722807, 
22.4276299180547, 22.5011424750138, 22.5621408760058, 22.4944203390804, 
22.5229715486123, 22.622312019965, 22.6507157318225, 22.6106757254605, 
22.6181855728448, 22.6297467977415, 22.6458690108391, 22.7187545265385, 
22.6957095238767, 22.706132832817, 22.6551536149017, 22.5499230156297, 
22.6232920327693, 22.5587827151805, 22.6575653854989, 22.618727517277, 
22.6249872062644, 22.6243261773279)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started, you were almost there. The last line of the function will return the model coefficients (minus the unit root test). You can add names to the list with `setNames`.

```
library(dplyr)

#Estimacion por cada sector
Modelo_MCO <- function(i) {

  Sector_elegido <- boyanza %>% 
    filter(Sector == serie_unica[i]) #Estimar cada serie por separado

  MCO <- lm(Sector_elegido$lrecaudacion ~ Sector_elegido$lpib) #Ejecutar el modelo MCO

  #Probar raiz unitaria / cointegracion
  coef(summary(MCO)) # here
}

lapply(1:length(serie_unica), Modelo_MCO) %>%
  setNames(serie_unica) # here

$Agropecuaria
                     Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         -8.790522  2.9215845 -3.008820 4.244507e-03
Sector_elegido$lpib  1.100120  0.1202964  9.145078 6.449666e-12

$Manufactura
                     Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         -5.980070 1.88292993 -3.175939 2.666331e-03
Sector_elegido$lpib  1.117588 0.07453399 14.994340 2.501412e-19
```

Comment: Works just fine. how can i turn that results list into a table? Also, if i try to input the unit root test right in the for loop, it brings only that result and forgets about all the other outputs. I tried with `adf.test(MCO$residuals)` and it didnt work. Please help me out there

Comment: For a tibble, update the last line in the function to `as_tibble(coef(summary(MCO))) # here`. I've never used `adf.test()`, it seems to produce a data frame, which won't fit into the tibble neatly.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function and gather all the values you need from each group in a dataframe.

```
apply_fun <- function(temp, name) {
   mod <- lm(lrecaudacion~lpib, temp)
   data.frame(name = name, a = mod$coefficients[1], b = mod$coefficients[2])
}
```

and then apply the function for each group

```
purrr::imap_dfr(split(boyanza, boyanza$Sector), apply_fun)

#          name     a    b
#1 Agropecuaria -8.79 1.10
#2  Manufactura -5.98 1.12
```

You can change the column names of the dataframe in the function and add all the necessary parameters that you need it to return.

Answer (score 0):

It requires a few packages, but `broom` & friends can be pretty powerful:

```r
library(broom)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tmp <- boyanza %>% 
    group_by(Sector) %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(models = map(data, function(x) lm(lrecaudacion ~ lpib, data = x))) %>%
    mutate(tidy_sum = map(models, function(x) tidy(x)))
```

You can then access individual summaries by `tmp$tidy_sum[[1]]`, etc.